# Get source_documents and score with ConversationalRetrievalChain, Stuff and Chailit UI

Tags: python, openai-api, information-retrieval, langchain, large-language-model

I'm having trouble trying to export the source documents and score from this code. I tried a bunch of things, but I can't retrieve it. The most I could do is to pass the my demand to the prompt so the LLM retrieves it to me, but sometimes it just ignores me or hallucinates (ex: it gives me a source link from inside the text). If I change chain_type to map_rerank and adapt a bit, I can get the source documents from a JSON (based on original saved metadata from my vectordb), but I want to use Stuff instead. Is there a way to get the source_documents and score from the answer? Or any metadata I originally have from the vectordb?

```
@on_chat_start
def init():
    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        deployment_name=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        model_name=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
        openai_api_base=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_version=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION,
        openai_api_key=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type=saci_constants.AZURE_OPEN_API_TYPE,
        temperature=saci_constants.TEMPERATURE,
        streaming=True,
        callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
    )

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        deployment=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_ADA_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        model=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_ADA_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME,
        openai_api_base=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_key=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type=saci_constants.AZURE_OPEN_API_TYPE,
        chunk_size=saci_constants.AZURE_CHUNK_SIZE,
    )

    faiss_db = FAISS.load_local(
        saci_constants.FAISS_DATABASE_PATH,
        embeddings,
    )

    retriever = faiss_db.as_retriever()

    messages = [SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(custom_prompts.SPARK)]
    messages.append(HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}"))
    spark_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)

    question_generator = LLMChain(
        llm=llm,
        prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
        verbose=True,
    )

    doc_chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(
        llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        prompt=spark_prompt,
        verbose=True,
    )

    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        llm=llm,
        memory_key="chat_history",
        return_messages=True,
        input_key="question",
        # output_key="answer",
        max_token_limit=1000,
        # k=1,
    )

    conversational_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
        retriever=retriever,
        question_generator=question_generator,
        combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
        memory=memory,
        rephrase_question=False,
        verbose=True,
        # output_key="answer",
    )

    # # Set chain as a user session variable
    cl.user_session.set("conversation_chain", conversational_chain)


@on_message
async def main(message: str):
    chat_history = []

    # Read chain from user session variable
    chain = cl.user_session.get("conversation_chain")

    # Run the chain asynchronously with an async callback
    res = chain(
        {"question": message, "chat_history": chat_history},
        callbacks=[cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler()],
    )

    print("aaaaaaaa", res)

    # Send the answer and the text elements to the UI
    await cl.Message(content=f"ANSWER: {res['answer']}").send()
```

Right now, the print I've got from res is this:

> aaaaaaaa {'question': 'Do I need to pay for OpenAI when doing RAG?', 'chat_history': [HumanMessage(content='Do I need to pay for OpenAI when doing RAG?', additional_kwargs={}, example=False), AIMessage(content="I'm not sure, but according to an article on Towards Data Science, setting up RAG can be a large initial investment, covering the integration, database access, and possibly even licensing fees. However, there is no mention of paying for OpenAI specifically. Would you like me to look up more information?", additional_kwargs={}, example=False)], 'answer': "I'm not sure, but according to an article on Towards Data Science, setting up RAG can be a large initial investment, covering the integration, database access, and possibly even licensing fees. However, there is no mention of paying for OpenAI specifically. Would you like me to look up more information?"}

Answer (score 3):

I got it. I just needed to add return_source_documents in ConversationalRetrievalChain:

```
    conversational_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
        retriever=retriever,
        question_generator=question_generator,
        combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
        memory=memory,
        rephrase_question=False,
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=True,
    )
```

Then I could retrieve all the metadata:

```
@on_message
async def main(message: str):
    chat_history = []

    # Read chain from user session variable
    chain = cl.user_session.get("conversation_chain")

    # Run the chain asynchronously with an async callback
    res = chain({"question": message, "chat_history": chat_history})
    print(res) # res has all the metadata if you need (chunk_id, document_id, content, source, etc.)

    sources = [doc.metadata.get("source") for doc in res["source_documents"]]
    chunk = [doc.metadata.get("chunk_id") for doc in res["source_documents"]]

    # Send the answer and the text elements to the UI
    await cl.Message(
        content=f"ANSWER: {res['answer']}, SOURCES: {set(sources)}, CHUNK: {set(chunk)}"
    ).send()
```

The score is something else. I guess it's something generated by the LLM itself, kind of an opinion, so sometimes it just doesn't answer, it isn't an objective metric. I thought it was based on the similarity_score when doing the information retrieval, but I guess it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Add the parameter`return_source_documents=True` in the ConversationalRetrievalChain will return the `source_documents` in res.

Your ConversationalRetrievalChain should look like

`conversational_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(retriever=retriever,question_generator=question_generator,combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,memory=memory,rephrase_question=False,verbose=True,return_source_documents=True,)`

then you should be able to get file name from metadata like this

`result = qa_chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})`

`filenames = "["+"][".join(set([x.metadata['filepath'] for x in result['source_documents']]))+"]"`